# updating Data time using mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) but i get this error when i'm trying to update datetime 
"SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated" I tried DateTime? instead of DateTime but it does not work

class :

```
public class Schedules
{
    [Key]
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

}
```

controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveEvent(Schedules e)
    {
        var status = false;
        using (DataBaseTabelModel dc = new DataBaseTabelModel())
        {
            if (e.EventID > 0)
            {
                var v = dc.Schedules.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {

                    v.Start = e.Start;
                    v.End = e.End;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dc.Schedules.Add(e);
            }
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
```

view :

```
        <div class="input-group date" id="dtp1">
            <input type="text" id="txtStart" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

                <div id="divEndDate" style="display:none">

                    <div class="input-group date" id="dtp2">
                        <input type="text" id="txtEnd" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function SaveEvent(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Scheduling/SaveEvent',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        //Refresh the calender
                        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                        $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is coming from SQL and is likely due to conversion between SQL Server's datetime2 and datetime types

The possible range of values represented by these types are:

- Datetime:  1753-01-01 00:00:00 -> 9999-12-31 23:59:59.997
- Datetime2: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 -> 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999

So it's easily possible that a valid Datetime2 value cannot be converted to a Datetime value.

.Net's DateTime has the same range as SQL Server's DateTime2.

If I were you I'd be checking the SQL types in tables, views and stored procedures to see where the coercion of the data is causing this mis-match.

Bear in mind that the default value for .Net's DateTime is 0001-01-01 00:00:00. If you're trying to pass an unset .Net DateTime to a Sql Server Datetime, this will likely fail with the exception you are seeing.

[Comparison of SQL Server's Datetime and Datetime2 types](https://sqlhints.com/2011/09/17/difference-between-datetime-and-datetime2-datatype/)

[Documentation for .Net DateTime](http://.Net%20DateTime%20documentation%7Chttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Phuzi the solution was adding globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-CO" in web.config